# Copy folders from server to another - Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, directory

I am trying to come up with a script to copy folders from one server to another. I might be going about this wrong, but I'm try to copy the directories from one server into an array, copy the directories from the second server into an array, compare them and then create the folders needed in the server that doesn't have them:

```
[array]$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path \\spesety01\TGT\TST\XRM\Test -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName 
[array]$folders2 = Get-ChildItem -Path \\sutwove02\TGT\TST\XRN -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName 


$folders | ForEach-Object {
    if ($folders2 -notcontains "$_") {
      New-Item "$_" -type directory


    }
}
```

The issue is that the "$_" (in the ForEach loop)refers to the server in "$folders" and when I run the script, I get an error that the folder already exists. Is there some way to specify to copy the folders to the new server? I accept that my approach might be completely off on this and I might be making it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: if you want the 2nd to have all the dirs in the 1st ... then just make ALL the 1st dirs in the 2nd. don't bother testing for it, just make it with error handling set to eat the errors.

Comment: Robocopy is a built-in windows application to do exactly what you're trying, if you want the "easy" way.

Comment: Would you need to create the directory on the remote server, not local?

Comment: Yes, I did not know that. Thank you for letting me know. I am (very) new here, so apologies and thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
using path A as reference, make any sub directories that are missing in path B
#>

Param(
    [string]$PathA,
    [string]$PathB
)

$PathADirs = (Get-ChildItem -Path $PathA -Recurse -Directory).FullName
$PathBDirs = (Get-ChildItem -Path $PathB -Recurse -Directory).FullName

$PreList = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $PathADirs -DifferenceObject $PathBDirs.replace($PathB,$PathA) | 
    Where-Object -Property SideIndicator -EQ "<=" |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'InputObject'

$TargetList = $PreList.Replace($PathA,$PathB)

New-Item -Path $TargetList -ItemType 'Directory'
```

Comment: This is beautiful and should be marked as the answer.

Comment: I don't get it @MackJ, if this answer was helpful why don't you mark it as answered since you asked the question?